# Locate all .pst files

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

**Greetings**

I have a problem with locating .pst files. **

### The task

** is to find all .pst files on a machine and create a list of them.

I tried to use Registry entry: "*HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\%OfficeVersion%\Outlook\Search\Catalog*". Looks like it contains list of all .**pst** & .**ost** files, but turned out it also has entries of deleted(or moved) files and it updates only if you connect .pst manually in Outlook. So if you move your old .pst in some kind of "Archive" my registry will not contain info about it.

I understand that looking through all files takes too much time, so I want to avoid that.

Also, keep in mind that user might have a lot of mailboxes and a lot of .pst(some of them might not even be connected to Outlook at all). And I can't use such things as Redemption or anything. Just plain C#(may be some C++ MAPI lib)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to search pst files all over in your system?

Comment: @skjoshi yes, that is the task. To search ALL pst files.

Comment: I can only see the possibility with the file search, but as the pst files are stored in the users directory you will have security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PST file locations is stored in the profile sections in the registry. The officially supported API designed to access and manipulate the profile data is the [IProfAdmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815345.aspx) interface (you can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) if you click the IProfAdmin button). PST path is stored in the `PR_PST_PATH` property. Extended MAPI can only be accessed from C++ or Delphi.

The profile data is stored in the registry, so in theory you could read the data from the registry, but the key names are profile specific and are generated randomly (profile section name is a guid). Also note that the profile data location in the registry is Outlook version specific.

You can use [ProfMan](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) (it comes with the distributable version of [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption)); ProfMan can be used from any language. The following script (VB) retrieves PST files names from all local profiles:

```
'Print the path to all the PST files in all profiles
 PR_PST_PATH = &H6700001E

 set Profiles=CreateObject("ProfMan.Profiles")
 for i = 1 to Profiles.Count
   set Profile = Profiles.Item(i)
   set Services = Profile.Services
   Debug.Print "------ Profile: " & Profile.Name & " ------"
   for j = 1 to Services.Count
     set Service = Services.Item(j)
     If (Service.ServiceName = "MSPST MS") or (Service.ServiceName = "MSUPST MS") Then
      MsgBox Service.Providers.Item(1).ProfSect.Item(PR_PST_PATH)
     End If
   next
 next
```

You can also retrieve PST file names from PST stores using the Outlook Object Model (but that requires Outlook to be running, and you can only do that for the currently used profile) - use the Store.FilePath property:

```
set vApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
for each vStore in vApp.Session.Stores
  MsgBox vStore.DisplayName & " - " & vStore.FilePath
next
```

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer. I tried to use Store.FilePath property. First, it says that there are 3 stores, 1st is .ost and file path is right. but 2 other stores have null file path value. Why is that?? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I just made a new .pst archive and tried using Oulook Object Model and it worked just right. Now I will just check if store is null.
I think getting list of attached .pst will work for now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Keep in mind that Store.FilePath only works for the active profile used in Outlook, which must be running.